# Can't use GPG to sign anything: "gpg2 signing failed: Operation cancelled"

Tags: 16.04, gnupg

Since some recent package upgrades to my xenial workstation, I found that I was no longer able to sign Git commits, where I'd get error messages like below, and where it would no longer pop up a dialog to enter my key passphrase:

```
$ git commit -S 
error: gpg failed to sign the data
fatal: failed to write commit object
```

With some searching, I came across [this 2016 page](http://www.jfcarter.net/~jimc/documents/bugfix/31-gpg-pinentry.html) talking about a mismatch between pinentry and gpg2 (I have my GPG program set to `gpg2` in my `.gitconfig`), and indeed like they mention, I have gpg2 2.1.x and pinentry 0.9.x:

```
$ gpg2 --version        
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11                                        
libgcrypt 1.6.5                                                        
$ pinentry --version    
pinentry-gnome3 (pinentry) 0.9.7
```

Another test they suggest fails similarly

```
$ echo test | gpg2 --clearsign 
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----                               
Hash: SHA256                                                     

test                                                             
gpg: signing failed: Operation cancelled                         
gpg: [stdin]: clearsign failed: Operation cancelled
```

I have a gpg-agent running, though I don't know if I trashed it by re-running `gpg-agent`. There doesn't seem to be any service that launches it.

I'm not sure if a recent update actually did put the gnupg2 package to 2.1.x, but I can't for the life of me find a 2.0.x to try to downgrade to, or a 1.x pinentry for xenial.

Is the page I was looking at a red herring? How do I go about signing things again?

---

PS. It started working again some days later, but I don't know what I did; nothing looks different. Maybe a restart fixed it? `:/`

```
$ gpg2 --version
gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11
libgcrypt 1.6.5
...
$ pinentry --version
pinentry-gnome3 (pinentry) 0.9.7
...
$ echo test | gpg2 --clearsign
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA256

test
-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v2

iQIcBAEBCAAGBQJbT0xjAAoJEAnk6ni30keKELoP/iGeP7PkxEsJSmCwgUMJpqWq
qIV/hobcZ2iqLi5WjCMtEAmJRwVu89GT0MW2wHl28t5+iJriW67pg4MoT1zKGSPN
```

Comment: All of a sudden the same just started happening to me in Mint 18.3 (Xenial-based). It worked last Wednesday, now it stopped. I haven't yet tried rebooting the workstation and I wouldn't like to do so.

I tried to run `echo test | gpg2 --passphrase mypassword --batch -a -s` and got the same `Operation canclelled`. Then I ran `pinentry-gnome3`, asked it for `getpin`, and entered some random "pin". It returned my data. Then I ran `pinentry-tty` (that previously failed) and also asked for `getpin`, entered random data, and got it back.

After those magic steps `gpg2` started working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but for anyone else who has this problem, you might have forgotten to run `git config --global user.signingkey yourkey`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the reason was, that my GPG-key was **expired**.

thech with `seahorse` what is the status of the key, you use in your git config, or on the console with

```
YOURKEY=$(git config -l | grep signingkey | cut -d"=" -f 2)
gpg2 -K --keyid-format SHORT | grep $YOURKEY -A3
```

Edit your key, so it does not expire too soon and then add it to your global config with

```
git config --global user.signingkey $YOURKEY
```

Maybe reboot your system to apply the changes